# How to stop wordpress from redirecting from the post's old slug after changing title and slug?

Tags: database, redirect, wp-redirect, template-redirect, wp-reset-postdata

After changing a post's title/slug from `mysite.com/name` to `mysite.com/new-name`, the old slug `mysite.com/name` is now redirecting to the new one `mysite.com/new-name`, and I don't want that to happen.

I understand that WordPress does that by default, using something called `_wp_old_slug`.

I ran this code on my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
$wpdb->query( "
DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_wp_old_slug'
" );
```

It did apparently remove all the old post slugs from my WordPress’s MySQL database, since now I can't find it there, at least not in the `wptf_postmeta` table.

After doing this "clean up", I tried to add `remove_action('template_redirect', 'wp_old_slug_redirect');`, again to the `functions.php` file.

The redirect is still occurring!

How can I completely disable this feature? Both on the current slug and also for future ones?

Comment: I think Yoast SEO does (or at least used to) do this as well; is that plugin active?

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide a higher priority number than the default when removing hooks.

If you leave it default there's a chance that your `remove_action` is executed prior to the **`add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_old_slug_redirect' )`**

So, instead:

`remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_old_slug_redirect', 20 );`

You also need to prevent WP from saving the old slugs which can be turned off by removing these filter hooks.

```
remove_action( 'post_updated', 'wp_check_for_changed_slugs', 20 );
remove_action( 'attachment_updated', 'wp_check_for_changed_slugs', 20);
```

Comment: @DanIsahac

Thank you brother. 

I tried adding `remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_old_slug_redirect', 20 );` however, the redirection still occurs. 

I want to note that adding `remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');` fixes the issue, but I don't think that it's the best way to solve this, since this command is not what I really want to do, it just happens that it solves this issue.

Comment: When removing callbacks from hooks, the priority needs to match exactly, otherwise it won't be removed. See the `remove_action()` doc: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/.